# Unable to parse the string based on search criteria using awk

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk, sed

I am getting a data in csv file from the server which is in below format

[image]

I need to parse only the text in the format`XENuw81506` instead of whole line

I used below awk command to filter out the data

`awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $3}' export.csv | awk '/XEN/'`

which gives me

```
XENuw81506 - JBoss HttpAdaptor JMXInvokerServlet is Accessible to 
XENux77290 - Multiple Red Hat JBoss Remote Arbitrary Code Execution
XENvc71430 Create Parent Rule For PIDs which
```

I am expecting my utility to filter out only

```
XENuw81506 
XENux77290 
XENvc71430
```

Comment: Don't attach an image. Provide text data from input file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, '/XEN/{sub(/ .*/,"",$3); print $3}' file
```

or

```
$ awk -F, '/XEN/{split($3,a," "); print a[1]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second awk, use `$1`

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $3}' export.csv | awk {'print $1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as there was no test data in reasonable format, I'm not going to bother with `FS`s and such, add an adequate one:

```
$ awk '{sub(/ .*/,"",$3); $0=$3} 1' export.csv
XENuw81506
XENux77290
XENvc71430
```